# TensorFlow find and mark multiple image boundaries

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision

My example is that I have an image with 5 other images on it. Whats the best way to have TensorFlow find/calculate the bounding boxes for each of those... need to take into account that in other images there might only be 3 separate images.

I've found that if I run a cv2.Laplacian on the source image it nicely outlines the 5 individual images but I'm not sure how best to use tensorflow to detect each of those bounding boxes?

UPDATE: My ONE issue is how do I use tensorflow to find each images boundaries? obviously I can find the 4 corners of the whole image but that doesn't help me - I need it to first know how many images their are and then find each of those boundaries.

Comment: This is an interesting problem; you'd think there would be an out-of-the-box trained up algorithm for this. Let's see if someone comes through with that. If your images are aligned (not skewed) then re-training an object detection algorithm might not require too many samples. If your images are night aligned strait, then I'd look for inspiration in a segmentation algorithm - train up a U-Net model to find all the pixels associated with each picture.... but there must be an easier way:)

Comment: Yes - then I was also thinking I could create some images ie black squares on a white background different sizes in one image then randomize it and use something like that to train — hmmm not sure though

Comment: YOLO might be worth looking into, perhaps an overkill but fun project. I have tested YOLO with made update data for line detection - attempt to have yolo determine location,mask and count.
https://github.com/pangyuteng/line-detection/blob/master/proto-line-detect-yolo.ipynb